# extract dynamically N-1 dimension tensor of N dimension tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

im struggling with this the following problem:

i have a fixed length list with M elements. this list contains M tensors, each are 3-dimensional with shape [p, q, s].

From that point, i need one 3-dimensional tensor with shape [p, q, s] but this tensor needs to be extracted from all the M tensors from the list.

This information is provided in an additional tensor with shape [p]. For every [p_n, :, :] with n = 1 , ...,  M there is an index-value that says from which of the M elements the data should come from.

This should work without iterating over a tensor, because the list has fixed size. but i can't solve that right now :-/

thanks for help! :-)

Example:

Given a list with M=3 3-dimensional tensors:

```
shape(m0) = [5, 7, 16]
shape(m1) = [5, 7, 16]
shape(m2) = [5, 7, 16]
```

and an index vector with len(index) = 5:

```
index = [0, 1, 1, 2, 0]
```

I want to compute a 3-dimensional tensor v with shape(v)=[5, 7, 16] that is:

```
v[0, :, :] = m1[0, :, :] because of index[0] = 1
v[1, :, :] = m1[1, :, :] because of index[0] = 1
v[2, :, :] = m1[2, :, :] because of index[0] = 1
v[3, :, :] = m2[3, :, :] because of index[0] = 2
v[4, :, :] = m0[4, :, :] because of index[0] = 0
```

I found a solution that works if shape(m0) = shape(m1) = shape(m2):

```
M = [m1, m2, m3]
v = []
for i in range(5):
    v.append(tf.gather(M, index[i])[:, i, :, :])
v = tf.stack(v)
```

No I want that this works if the shapes of m0, m1 and m2 differ. for example:

```
shape(m0) = [5, 7, 16]
shape(m1) = [5, 8, 16]
shape(m2) = [5, 9, 16]
```

I solved this with zero-padding the tensors to the biggest shape in the list. But I want a solution without padding. then the solution could not be a tensor with shape [5, 9, 16] but a list of length 5 with different shapes, e. g.:

```
v = [v0, v1, v2, v3, v4]
shape(v0) = [5, 7, 16]
shape(v0) = [5, 8, 16]
shape(v0) = [5, 8, 16]
shape(v0) = [5, 9, 16]
shape(v0) = [5, 9, 16]
```

the problem is that i dont know the second dimension(7 or 8 or 9) of the tensors at graph-built time.

Comment: It will help if you show a simple example.

Comment: i did. hopefully one can better understand this